# Hide entire tr row in a php loop with jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to hide the entire tr row in my php loop if the value of td input is 0. The script works here: http://jsfiddle.net/jmg2u98a/3/ but with the php loop it just hides all questions and i don't know why?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".btn1").click(function () {
   $(".hide-also").each(function(){
    if($(this).find("td input").val()==0)
      $(this).hide();
  });

 });
 $(".btn2").click(function () {
   $('td:has(input[value=0]), .hide-also').show();
 });
});
<script>

<button class="btn1">Hide</button>
<button class="btn2">Show</button>

<?php
$vals=array(0,1,2);
$result = @mysqli_query($con, $query);
if ($result) {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $body = $row['question_body'];
    $question_id = $row['question_id'];

    echo '<tr class="hide-also">
    <td class="question">'.$body.'</td>';
    foreach($vals as $x){
      $s='';
      if($x==$row['answer_value']){
        $s="checked";
      }
      echo '<td class="answer"><input type="radio" name="answer_value['.$question_id.']" value="'.$x.'" '.$s.'></td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
  }
}
?>

db:
questions
question_id question_body
    1         Question1
    2         Question2
answers
question_id answer_value
    1            0
    2            1
```

I use a join to get question_id question_body answer_value to output.

```
SELECT answers.question_id, question_body, answer_value FROM answers LEFT JOIN questions on answers.question_id = questions.question_id where question_sort=1 AND form_id=$formid
```

Comment: Please Try This:

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645088/how-to-show-hide-table-row-with-jquery-in-while-loop)

Comment: have you checked `$x` is actually not zero for all rows and what is `$vals` - you haven't shown where it is defined

Comment: you already have it working on the fiddle, just create the markup just the same

Comment: @Ghost ghost i'm trying to do that, but its not working.

Comment: @Pete $x is 0 or 1 or 2 in this case.

Comment: @user3906056 so the final rendered html markup matches the one on the fiddle? if the output with the php fetch and from the fiddle is just the same, then just use the js from the fiddle

Comment: @Mohsin I dont think that is what i'm looking for. I'm looking to hide rows with a the value 0

Comment: The jquery you have posted above is different from the jsfiddle, are you sure you have used the correct jquery too

Comment: @Ghost as i see it i use  the same render as fiddle, but right know in my php it hides all rows. So I'm missing something.

Comment: @user3906056 i think i have an answer but not so sure, but its hard to test since i can't replicate your db values and loop them as you have on your environment

Comment: @ghost i have added a db markup in the question

Comment: @user3906056 i don't think it will help this case, most likely will help is that `$vals`, the contents of that.

Comment: @ghost $vals=array(0,1,2)

Comment: @user3906056 so actually this echoes three radio boxes per row?

Comment: @Ghost Yes I'm sorry i dint realized i missed that. The loop gets answer_value from a form_id with an value of 0 or 1 or 2. Thats why i want to hide questions with value 0.